# "product-review-table" is not showing in review form

Tags: review, product-page, magento1.9.2.3

After clicking on "Be the first to review this product", in review form the table to display the rating-box is missing (attached image) and it only displays the form-list's input fields like "Let us know your thoughts"... [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need enable that fields in Admin.

> *Admin -> Catalog -> Reviews and Ratings -> Manage Ratings*

Then enable or add new.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Why Always thinking something is really wrong here, ahhh...Thanks man

Comment: Something just seems to be wrong :D
Good luck!